# Separating Overlapping Date Ranges in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have data with overlapping data ranges. Example below

| Customer_ID | FAC_NUM | Start_Date | End_Date | New_Monies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | ABC1234 | 26/NOV/2014 | 26/MAY/2015 | 100000 |
| 12345 | ABC1234 | 12/DEC/2014 | 12/JUN/2015 | 200000 |
| 12345 | ABC1234 | 15/JUN/2015 | 15/DEC/2015 | 500000 |
| 12345 | ABC1234 | 20/DEC/2015 | 20/JUN/2016 | 600000 |

I want to convert this table into data with non overlapping ranges such that for each overlapping period, the New_Monies column is summed together and shown as a new row. For the example above, I want the output to be as follows

| Customer_ID | FAC_NUM | Start_Date | End_Date | New_Monies |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12345 | ABC1234 | 26/NOV/2014 | 11/DEC/2014 | 100000 |
| 12345 | ABC1234 | 12/DEC/2014 | 26/MAY/2015 | 300000 |
| 12345 | ABC1234 | 27/MAY/2015 | 12/JUN/2015 | 200000 |
| 12345 | ABC1234 | 15/JUN/2015 | 15/DEC/2015 | 500000 |
| 12345 | ABC1234 | 20/DEC/2015 | 20/JUN/2016 | 600000 |

Row 2 above being the overlapping period of 12 Dec 2014 to 26 May 2015 showing the total New_Monies as 300000 (100000+200000)

What would be the best way to do this in Oracle?

Thanks in advance for your support.

Regards,
Ani

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
with
  prep (customer_id, fac_num, dt, amount) as (
    select t.customer_id, t.fac_num,
           case h.col when 's' then t.start_date else t.end_date + 1 end as dt,
           case h.col when 's' then t.new_monies else - t.new_monies end as amount
    from   sample_data t 
           cross join
           (select 's' as col from dual union all select 'e' from dual) h
  )
, cumul_sums (customer_id, fac_num, dt, amount) as (
    select distinct
           customer_id, fac_num, dt, 
           sum(amount) over (partition by customer_id, fac_num order by dt)
    from   prep
  )
, with_intervals (customer_id, fac_num, start_date, end_date, amount) as (
    select customer_id, fac_num, dt, 
           lead(dt) over (partition by customer_id, fac_num order by dt) - 1,
           amount
    from   cumul_sums
  )
select customer_id, fac_num, start_date, end_date, amount
from   with_intervals
where  end_date is not null
order  by customer_id, fac_num, start_date
;
```

The `prep` subquery unpivots the inputs, while at the same time changing the "end date" to the "start date" of the following interval and assigning a positive amount to the "start date" and the negative of the same amount to the following "start date". `cumul_sums` computes the cumulative sums; note that if two or more intervals begin on the same date (so the same date from `prep` appears multiple times for a customer and `fac_num`), the analytic `sum` will include the amounts from ALL the rows up to that date - the default windowing clause is **`range`** `between.....`. After the cumulative sums are computed, this subquery also de-duplicates the output rows (to handle precisely that complication, of multiple intervals starting on the same date). `with_intervals` recovers the "start date" - "end date" intervals, and the final step simply removes the last interval ("to infinity") which would have an "amount" of zero.

**EDIT** *This solution answers the OP's original question. After posting the solution, the OP changed the question. The solution can be changed easily to address the new formulation. I'm not going to chase shadows though; the solution will remain as is.*

Comment: @Aniruddha - so, I suppose what you are saying is that you don't want to see the intervals where the "amount" is 0. And you weren't able to figure out yourself what modification you need to make to the query? It's a trivial change to the WHERE clause; I will let you work on it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an way to do this.

```
 with all_data
      as (select Customer_ID,FAC_NUM,start_date as dt,new_monies as calc_monies
            from t
          union all
          select Customer_ID,FAC_NUM,end_date as dt,new_monies*-1 as calc_monies
            from t
         )
select x.customer_id
       ,x.fac_num
       ,x.start_date
       ,case when row_number() over(order by end_date desc)=1 then 
            x.end_date + 1
            else x.end_date
         end as new_end_date
  from (         
    select t.customer_id
           ,t.fac_num
           ,t.dt as start_date
           ,lead(dt) over(order by dt)-1 as end_date
           ,sum(calc_monies) over(order by dt) as new_monies
      from all_data t
     )x
where end_date is not null 
order by 3
```

db fiddle link
https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=856c9ac0954e45429994f4ac45699e6f

```
+-------------+---------+------------+--------------+------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | FAC_NUM | START_DATE | NEW_END_DATE | NEW_MONIES |
+-------------+---------+------------+--------------+------------+
|       12345 | ABC1234 | 26-NOV-14  | 11-DEC-14    |     100000 |
|       12345 | ABC1234 | 12-DEC-14  | 25-MAY-15    |     300000 |
|       12345 | ABC1234 | 26-MAY-15  | 12-JUN-15    |     200000 |
+-------------+---------+------------+--------------+------------+
```